# Which string will always have a positive compareTo return value, regardless to which other string it is compared?

Tags: java

I would like to know biggest possible string in the sort system. When I sort in increasing order, it will be guarenteed that this item is going to position itself at the bottom. I will use this string to position empty cells at the bottom.

I tried "zzzzzzzzzzz" string , but it does not work in some cases.

```
mainPersonnelList.sort((Personnel o1, Personnel o2) -> {
        String o1Str = o1.getPersonnelName();
        String o2Str = o2.getPersonnelName();
        if(o1Str.isEmpty()){o1Str = "zzzzzzzzzzz";}
        if(o2Str.isEmpty()){o2Str = "zzzzzzzzzzz";}
        return o1Str.compareTo(o2Str);
    });
```

Which string should I use?

Comment: compare by length?

Comment: @Antoniossss But I am not comparing by lenght , I am comparing by characters. So in your case "aaaaaaaa" will be at the bottom and the "z" will be at top.

Comment: The largest possible Java string has 2^31 - 1 characters in it.  Are you really sure you want that?

Comment: I think your question is, "which string to choose which will always have a positive `compareTo` return value, regardless to which other string it is compared?". Is that correct?

Comment: You should update your question accordingly then, as many readers seem to understand it wrong ("biggest possible" is quite misleading here)

Comment: Yes that is correct. Sorry for miss explanation and bad title. It could be just one character which is not used in any circumstances. But @Mad Physicist solution solved my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no limit to the size of a string as far as you're concerned. The limit is defined by the size of a pointer and the amount of available memory, neither of which will help you make a working program. And don't forget, not only do you want the longest string, but it must be filled with the maximum character as well. There are characters beyond `z` out there, making this a fine example of an XY problem.

Just remember what a comparator returns: an integer that indicates the direction of the comparison. You are already testing for empty elements, so always moving them down is trivial:

```
mainPersonnelList.sort((Personnel o1, Personnel o2) -> {
        String o1Str = o1.getPersonnelName();
        String o2Str = o2.getPersonnelName();
        if(o1Str.isEmpty()){
            return o2Str.isEmpty() ? 0 : -1;
        }
        if(o2Str.isEmpty()){return 1;}
        return o1Str.compareTo(o2Str);
    });
```

The ternary check is there to make sure the sort stays consistent, and stable.